# How to check for link regex in text with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec

I have a string of html that looks like this:

```
Click the link below:
<a href="http://example.com/foo/bar?token=1HwyaHz2XX4sEEgqng9M">Verify</a>
```

I would like to check for the presence of the link, but substitute wildcards for the params that I don't care about. I've tried this but it doesn't match:

```
expect(html).to match %r{<a href="http://example.com/foo/bar?token=(.+)">Verify</a>}
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape special characters that could be interpreted as regex matchers. Here the `?`

```
expect(html).to match %r{<a href="http://example.com/foo/bar\?token=(.+)">Verify</a>}
```